# Getting NullReferenceException on IIS Express while running from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I am trying to do CRUD operation on a table from a database (Oracle18c hosted on remote server)- "Items" which has item and UnitWeight as columns. This is my first ASP.NET project. Just following a tutorial that I found online (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/crud-operation-in-asp-net-core30-with-oracle-database2). I was able to follow the steps without any issue. But when I am trying to run the project in IIS Express I am getting following error in the picture. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

I am giving my snippets below.

Items.cs [Models]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cs550.Models
{
public class Items
    {
    public string item { get; set; }
    public int unitWeight { get; set; }

    }
}
```

itemService.CS [Services]

```
using cs550.Interface;
using cs550.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cs550.Services
{
    public class itemService : IItemService
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        public itemService(IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("OracleDBConnection");
        }
        public IEnumerable<Items> getAllItem()
        {
            List<Items> itemList = new List<Items>();
             using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select item, unitWeight from Items";
                    OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while(rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Items item = new Items
                        {
                            item = rdr["item"].ToString(),
                            unitWeight = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["unitWeight"])

                        };
                        itemList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return itemList;
        }

    public Items getItemByItem(string it)
    {
        Items items = new Items();
         using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select item, unitWeight from Items Where item="+it+"";
                OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    items.item = rdr["item"].ToString();
                    items.unitWeight = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["unitWeight"]);
                }
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
    
    public void AddItems(Items it)
    {
        try
        {
             using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Items(item, unitWeight) Values('"+it.item+"',"+it.unitWeight+")";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void EditItems(Items it)
    {
        try
        {
             using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "Update Items Set unitWeight="+it.unitWeight+" where item='"+it.item+"'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
}
```

IItemService.cs [Interface]

```
using cs550.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cs550.Interface
{
    public interface IItemService
    {
        IEnumerable<Items> getAllItem();
        Items getItemByItem(string it);

        void AddItems(Items it);

        public void EditItems(Items it);
    }
}
```

Strtup.CS

```
using cs550.Interface;
using cs550.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cs550
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IItemService, itemService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Items/Index", "");
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Items}/{action=Index}/{item?}");
        });
    }
}
}
```

appsetting.JSON

```
{
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  }
},
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "OracleDBConnection": "User Id=myUserID;Password=myPassword; Data Source= remoteURL:1521/DB"
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

ItemController.cs

```
using cs550.Interface;
using cs550.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cs550.Controllers
{
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        IItemService itemService;

        public ItemsController(IItemService _itemService)
        {
            itemService = _itemService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Items> items = itemService.getAllItem();
            return View();
        }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Items it)
    {
        itemService.AddItems(it);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string item)
    {
        Items it = itemService.getItemByItem(item);
        return View(it);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Items it)
    {
        itemService.EditItems(it);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
}
```

My Razor Pages:

Index.cshtml

```html
@model IEnumerable<cs550.Models.Items>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.item)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.unitWeight)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.unitWeight)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item  }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=item })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Create.cshtml

```html
@model cs550.Models.Items

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Items</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="item" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="item" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="item" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="unitWeight" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="unitWeight" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="unitWeight" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Edit.cshtml

```html
@model cs550.Models.Items

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Items</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="item" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="item" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="item" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="unitWeight" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="unitWeight" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="unitWeight" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Where is your controller and how you making the request?

Comment: @MestreDosMagros Apologies! Updated the thread with the controller information

Comment: Your `cmd` is not bound to a connection. The example/tutorial uses `cmd = con.CreateCommand()` whereas you are using `cmd = new OracleCommand()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Change:
```

```
     using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
                {
```

To:

```
      using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
     {  
              using(OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
              {
```

You have to use PL/SQL text in your data reader, or you can create a stored procedure and use ref cursor to work with data

Also change :

```
public class itemController : Controller
```

To

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
```

Change your action Index code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Items> items = itemService.getAllItem();
            return View(items);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I am getting a different error now.

Comment: Invalid Operation Exception. Updated the thread with the picture

Comment: You have to use PL/SQL text in your data reader, or you can create a stored procedure and use cursor  and input parameters to get data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, got passed that error but getting something else now :(

Comment: Check my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

`Error 404 Not Found` is a client side error which states that the resource you are searching is not found. Here the resource you are searching is `Index` in `items`.
In `Startup.cs` you have mentioned the route as `{controller=Items}/{action=Index}/{item?}`. So on load it will search for a controller named as `Items` and then `Index` action will be executed. Here the controller name is different which is `item` and hence the `Index` action could not be found. So changing it to correct controller name to `public class ItemsController : Controller` will fix the `404` issue.
Please add http verbs (Post, Get, Put, Delete) to the actions if you want to use it in routes. Here some methods like `Edit` are missing those verbs.
One more thing to note is here you are not adding any razor pages, so I expect you will be calling the route directly in browser or using tool like postman/fiddler. So when you start IISExpress it will go to `localhost:<port number>` which is mapped to default route. So if you want to access any specific action please change the method of calling, like Get or Post and add proper routing path.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have razor pages added, updated the thread